# Why is this if() statement in onDeviceReady looping?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

In my Phonegap Android app, I have this Javascript code:

```
function onDeviceready()
{
    window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url)
    {
            alert("window location is: " + window.location);
            if (window.location !== 'file:///android_asset/www/confirmation.html')
            {
                window.location = "file:///android_asset/www/confirmation.html";
            }
    });
}
```

It seems to me that if window.location is anything other than `file:///android_asset/www/confirmation.html`, then it should go to `file:///android_asset/www/confirmation.html`. If it's already on that page, then nothing should happen.

But, what is happening is that it reloads `file:///android_asset/www/confirmation.html` over and over without stopping.

A little searching on the web indicates that in the context of an Android device, one should use `navigator.app.loadUrl()` instead of `window.location`, but this code still loops:

```
function onDeviceready()
{
    window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url)
    {
            alert("window location is: " + window.location);
            if (window.location !== 'file:///android_asset/www/confirmation.html')
            {
                navigator.app.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/confirmation.html");
            }
    });
}
```

How do I stay on `file:///android_asset/www/confirmation.html` if I am already on `file:///android_asset/www/confirmation.html` when I come through my `onDeviceready` code?

Comment: In the if statement you have '!==', it should be '!='.  I doubt this is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.location` is [an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location), not a string, so that comparison won't work.

Maybe try `window.location.href != 'http://....'`

Where the confusion comes from is that even though it is an object, you can still assign a String to it (to change the URL).

Comment: Just as a note, now that I'm using `window.location.href`, `!==` works as well as `!=`. I go with `!==` because if I don't, Netbeans complains at me with warnings.

Comment: Was this the solution? If so could you please mark it as answered? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure window.location will always return what you're comparing to. It's perhaps better idea to compare to a substring of the URL instead of the whole path:

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('onfirmation.html') > -1)
{
    navigator.app.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/confirmation.html");
}
```

Also, as noted by Thilo, window.location is an object, not a string - but a simple "==" instead of "===" would work there as well I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function onDeviceready()
{
    window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url)
    {
           var activePage = $.mobile.activePage.attr("id");

    if(activePage!="confirmation")// confirmation is page id of confirmation.html page
      {

        $.mobile.changePage('confirmation.html');
        // confirmation.html is not in same folder then put '../foldername/confirmation.html'

       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this solution require jQuery mobile?